# j2me+Reverse geocoding

Tags: java, java-me, geocoding

I had used the `MidMap` Google API as per the link given below in my project: http://www.jappit.com/blog/midmaps-g...va-me-library/

It is working properly. But now I want to do reverse geocoding. Where I programmatic pass the longitude-latitude and through the use of google api i want to get the address(location) of that.

---

**Edit**: I had tried to implement this:

```
url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&   sensor=true";              
  HttpConnection cnx = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);    
  InputStream is=cnx.openInputStream();
  StringBuffer b=new StringBuffer();
  int car;
  while( (car=is.read())!= -1){
      b.append((char)car);
  }
  is.close();
  cnx.close();
  String res=b.toString();</code></pre>
```

It is showing the error on the `InputStream is=cnx.openInputStream();` line. The error is:

> java.io.IOException: malformed header
>   field 
>           at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.readHeaders(),
>   bci=198
>           at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.finishRequestGetResponseHeader(),
>   bci=45
>           at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(),
>   bci=47
>           at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(),
>   bci=3
>           at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.openInputStream(),
>   bci=6
>           at httpmislet.run(httpmislet.java:46)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(), bci=11 java.io.IOException: malformed
>   header field

I know I need to use XML parsing.

Comment: Could you please tell which package have you used HttpConnection and Connector classes? Is it javax.microedition.io?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google provides  [Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) also for example

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I had tries to implement this   url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true";               HttpConnection cnx = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);      InputStream is=cnx.openInputStream();
      StringBuffer b=new StringBuffer();

Answer (score 1):

Nokia forum [How to get Location Using Location API JSR 179](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_get_Location_Using_Location_API_JSR_179)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I know this.The thing i want to know is how to do reverse geocoding i.e i want address info from longitude-latitude.